# Position and orientation of local coordinate system relative to another local coordinate system (both described in world coord. system)

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, transformation, quaternions, orientation

This question might have been answered before, but I couldn't find one that will best describe my problem, or before I got confused.

The following image depicts three coordinate systems: a world coordinate system, **W**, and two local coordinate systems **A** and **B** described in the world coordinate system in terms of their position, **T**, and orientation in quaternion format, **Q** (all relative to **W**):

[Coordinate systems in 3D space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRYTO.jpg)

- $T_A$ - position of the origin of coordinate system **A**, in the world coordinate system, **W**.
- $T_B$ - position of the origin of coordinate system **B**, in the world coordinate system, **W**.
- $Q_A$ - orientation of coordinate system **A**, in (with reference to) the world coordinate system, **W** (in quaternions).
- $Q_B$ - orientation of coordinate system **B**, in the world coordinate system, **W** (in quaternions).
- $t_{BA}$ - position of the origin of coordinate system **B**, inside (with reference to) coordinate system **A**.
- $q_{BA}$ - orientation of coordinate system **B**, described in terms of (with reference to) coordinate system **A**.

I would like to get $t_{BA}$ and $q_{BA}$ (with reference to coordinate system **A**)? Or basically, the position and orientation of coordinate system **B** from an observer's perspective standing at (and inside) coordinate system **A**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you could find out that $t_{BA} = T_B - T_A$ and $q_{BA}=(Q_A)^{-1}Q_B$:

Let $\mathbf{x_P^W}= (x^W_P,y^W_P,z^W_P)$ be the coordinates $(x^W_P,y^W_P,z^W_P)$ or the position $\mathbf{x_P^W}$ of ***any*** point $P$ measured along the $x$-,$y$- and $z$-axis of the world coordinate system $W$. If the $x$-,$y$- and $z$- coordinates or the positions of the origins $0_A$ and $0_B$ of the coordinate systems $A$ and $B$ with respect to the world coordinate system $W$ are $\mathbf{x_{0_A}^W} = (x_{0_A}^W,y_{0_A}^W,z_{0_A}^W)$ and $\mathbf{x_{0_B}^W} = (x_{0_B}^W,y_{0_B}^W,z_{0_B}^W)$, then the position of the **arbitrary** point $P$ with respect to $A$ and $B$ can be calculated as (just [vector addition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html) in $A$ or in $B$)

$$\mathbf{x_P^A}= -\mathbf{x_{0_A}^W}+\mathbf{x_P^W}=(x^W_P-x_{0_A}^W,y^W_P-y_{0_A}^W,z^W_P-z_{0_A}^W)$$

$$\mathbf{x_P^B}= -\mathbf{x_{0_B}^W}+\mathbf{x_P^W}=(x^W_P-x_{0_B}^W,y^W_P-y_{0_B}^W,z^W_P-z_{0_B}^W)$$

Now fix this point $P$ and make it equal the origin $0_B$ of the coordinate system $B$, let $\mathbf{x_P^W}=\mathbf{x_{0_B}^W}=(x_{0_B}^W,y_{0_B}^W,z_{0_B}^W)$, then the equations above will become

$$\mathbf{x_{0_B}^A}= -\mathbf{x_{0_A}^W}+\mathbf{x_{0_B}^W}=(x_{0_B}^W-x_{0_A}^W,y_{0_B}^W-y_{0_A}^W,z_{0_B}^W-z_{0_A}^W)$$

$$\mathbf{x_{0_B}^B}= -\mathbf{x_{0_B}^W}+\mathbf{x_{0_B}^W}=(x_{0_B}^W-x_{0_B}^W,y_{0_B}^W-y_{0_B}^W,z_{0_B}^W-z_{0_B}^W)$$

The first equation is saying: the $x$-,$y$- and $z$-coordinates of the origin $0_B$ of the coordinate system $B$ measured along the $x$-,$y$- and $z$-axis of the coordinate system $A$ are $$(x_{0_B}^W-x_{0_A}^W,y_{0_B}^W-y_{0_A}^W,z_{0_B}^W-z_{0_A}^W)$$

The second equation is saying: the $x$-,$y$- and $z$-coordinates of the origin $0_B$ of the coordinate system $B$ measured along the $x$-,$y$- and $z$-axis of the coordinate system $B$ are $$(0,0,0)$$

Look [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g-spring2016/lectures/7a-Quaternions_Orientation.pdf) and [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-17-winter/Papers/quaternion.pdf) and [here](https://www.3dgep.com/understanding-quaternions/) and [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/dont-get-lost-in-deep-space-understanding-quaternions/) for some information about orientation. I just found this [powerpoint presentation part 1 of 2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiN8bHM3dDjAhU86KYKHffHBzoQFjACegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnescacademy.nasa.gov%2Freview%2Fdownloadfile.php%3Ffile%3DIntroductiontoQuaternionsPart1of2.pptx%26id%3D57%26distr%3DPublic&usg=AOvVaw1pAzBxlK2TDcaZT8q0EUKq)  and [powerpoint presentation part 2 of 2 (see page 19)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiYoIaB4NDjAhUC4KYKHf-fCEcQFjABegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnescacademy.nasa.gov%2Freview%2Fdownloadfile.php%3Ffile%3DIntroductiontoQuaternionsPart2of2V2.pptx%26id%3D58%26distr%3DPublic&usg=AOvVaw08SD_Bdomu6wxgKn6uurDB) which is stating that:

If $Q_A^W$ is quaternion for orientation of reference frame $A$ relative to some base reference frame $W$ and $Q_B^W$ is quaternion for orientation of another reference frame $B$ relative to that same base reference frame $W$, then $Q^{A}_{B}=(Q_A)^{-1}Q_B$ is a quaternion for orientation of reference frame $B$ relative to reference frame $A$ where $Q_A^{-1}$ is [inverse](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-inverse-of-a-quaternion) of $Q_A$ (if quaternions are unit quaternions, then $Q^{-1}=Q^{*}$ ([conjugate](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuaternionConjugate.html))).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the effort and extra reading material you've put into the answer. I appreciate it! Those powerpoints on quaternions are great.